# Extracting HTTP content in bash doesn't work with nc output

Tags: bash, http, pipe, netcat, busybox

Let's say I have this HTTP response:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 5
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en,*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:55764

Hello
```

And I'm interested only in content ("Hello"). I found this command to work if the text is fed from a file:

```
cat data.txt | tr '\n' '#' | sed "s/.*##//" | tr '#' '\n'
Hello
```

where data.txt contains the text above.
But if I try to feed it with the output of `nc`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n" | ./busybox-armv7l nc -l -p 55764 | tr '\n' '#' | sed "s/.*##//" | tr '#' '\n'
done
```

it doesn't work, i.e. it just print out everything:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 5
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en,*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:55764

HelloPOST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 5
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en,*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:55764

Hello
```

Why the piping works with `cat` but not with `nc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

output of nc goes to stderr just add `&` after second `|` to make the pipe effective:

`echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n" | ./busybox-armv7l nc -l -p 55764 |& tr '\n' '#' | sed "s/.*##//" | tr '#' '\n`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. It still prints out all the stuff.

Comment: Can you please tell me your bash version? `bash --version`

Comment: and why you are using busybox?

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.3.0(1)-release (arm-poky-linux-gnueabi)`. I'm using busybox because it's an embedded device and I have a limited set of commands only.

Comment: but you are using bash to interpret the whole script: `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Changing the shebang to `/bin/busybox-armv7l sh` leads to `syntax error: unexpected "&"`. Without `&` the behavior is the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183841/discussion-between-gopy-and-mark).

Comment: I tested the solution, this works for me, the only difference is that I used busybox instead of ./busybox-armv7l . I can't guess your problem. be sure that your input(http request) doesn't contain '\r\n' s

Comment: Fixed. The problem was '\r\n' in the request (made with `XMLHttpRequest`). Changing the command to `echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n" | ./busybox-armv7l nc -l -p 55764 | tr '[\r\n]' '#' | sed "s/.*##//" | tr '#' '\n'` did the trick.